# Driving into Tijuana, how do I get a tourist card (FMM)? Do I need one?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, mexico, fmm-tourist-card

I will be driving into Mexico for my first time. I am a U.S. citizen and will be in Mexico for about 4 days in the Tijuana area. I've read online that I need to get an FMM form because I will be there for more than 72 hours, do I need to do this before I enter Mexico? Is the process obvious enough for me to figure out on the spot or should I keep doing research so I know exactly what to expect when I cross the border into Mexico.

Comment: Related if not somewhat duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43935/what-exactly-is-a-fm-t-mexico-tourist-card

Comment: What to expect? Murder, mayhem and kidnapping...and a cantina full of vampires.

Comment: Technically you won't need a FFM, but make sure you insurance from US cover mexican territory, most of them would extend coverage for about 20 miles after crossing the border. There is some good information here [FMM](https://www.busycactus.com/travelinfo/fmm-cards-or-mexican-tourist-cards/) and here [Vehicle permits](https://www.busycactus.com/travelinfo/vehicle-permits-banjercito/)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Baja Bound Site](http://www.bajabound.com/before/permits/visa.php):

> **How do I obtain a tourist card (FMM)?**
>
> Most tourists who drive across the border obtain their tourist card from an immigration office at the border crossing. They are also available at border zone airports, airlines flying to Mexico, travel agencies and other ports. Tourist cards are no longer available at Mexican Consulates. Keep in mind that if you obtain your tourist card before crossing the border, you will still have to stop at the Mexican immigration office at the border to document your entry date and to have your tourist card stamped by immigration officials.

So you will get the card at the border crossing.

Comment: Note that this requires a little bit of attention.  As I recall from a trip several years ago, you can drive straight across the border from San Diego to Tijuana without going through a staffed checkpoint.  In your case you *want* to stop, so you will have to watch for the appropriate place to turn off.  If you miss it, it may be hard to figure out how to get back there without re-entering the US first. Also, you'll want to carefully read the other info on the Baja Bound page; in particular, you will need to bring your US passport.

Comment: @NateEldredge Mexico opened a [new checkpoint here in 2012](http://www.utsandiego.com/news/2012/Oct/30/mexicos-el-chaparral-crossing-opens-thursday/).

Comment: They don't check at the new crossing either

Answer (score 1):

Unlike at most borders, the road doesn't automatically take you through passport control, meaning you drive through the border unchecked.

You can obtain an FMM in advance [HERE](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html)

Or, alternatively, locate an immigration office shortly after crossing the border, where you obtain the FMM and passport stamp.

And yes, you do need it for staying more than 72 hours; however unless running into a police check, you can get away with not obtaining it in practice - as again Mexico doesn't operate border checks at the border with the US.