# Who can use the CBX Bridge between Mexico and the United States?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, borders, mexico, san-diego

Can a passport holder of any country use the [CBX](https://www.crossborderxpress.com/) (Cross Border Express) bridge? I would usually obtain a visa on entry if I flew to Mexico, so would I obtain the same taking the CBX bridge ?

Is it basically the same as a walked border crossing except you pay for the express feature?

Is it easy to catch a bus/shuttle from San Diego International Airport or from the city to the CBX bridge?

Comment: It is unclear what your exact situation is. You claim to get a 'visa on entry' when flying to Mexico, but there is no such thing as a visa on entry or visa on arrival in the Mexican immigration regulations. You are either free to enter without a visa *or* you need to get a visa in advance. Unless you refer to the Mexican Electronic Authorization System, which excempts some citizens from the visa requirement, but using that way, you still don't get a 'visa on entry'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo He is most likely referring to the [tourist card](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43935/3221).

Answer (score 6):

[You can only use](https://www.crossborderxpress.com/travel-requirements) the CBX bridge if you:

- Are legally able to enter Mexico or the United States, depending on your direction of travel, *and*
- Have a boarding pass for a flight which:

  - Departs from TIJ within the next 24 hours, *or*
  - Arrived at TIJ within the last 2 hours
- Purchase a CBX ticket

Except for the requirement to buy a ticket for the CBX, and the boarding pass requirement, it works much the same way as any other *airport* border crossing.

In particular, unlike at land border crossings, on entering Mexico you *will* speak to Mexican immigration officers and be required to have a visa if nationals of your country require a visa to visit parts of Mexico other than the US border area. Because CBX is intended to serve people flying in and out of TIJ, either to points further in Mexico or to international destnations, it's not considered part of the US border adjacent area where many people would be visa-exempt.

If you need a [tourist card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43935/3221), you should pick it up from Mexican immigration at CBX. Flights out of TIJ to elsewhere in Mexico are domestic, and you won't be able to obtain one afterward (which can cause you a lot of headache later!).

Because of this, CBX is not a good crossing point for people who are merely visiting Tijuana.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not make it very clear. I emailed them an they answered the questions for me.

Question: I am a New Zealander going to travel in the USA, Mexico, and Central America. As a New Zealand passport holder can I use the CBX bridge to cross into Mexico and obtain a Visa on Entry.

Answer: Absolutely. You will need your boarding pass and passport and once you enter Mexico, immigration will direct you to get your permit.

Comment: You would need to have a boarding pass for a flight departing from TIJ in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Yip I understand that cheers for the reply